# Laravel - Is there a way to run a queued job from another queued job on different queue?

Tags: laravel, queue, backend

Imagine:

1- Eating job

2- Drinking job

3- Eating Queue

4- Drinking Queue

If I have an Eating Job running on Eating queue and from this job I want to run Drinking Job but on Drinking Queue.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found what solves my problem.

Instead of using `php artisan queue:work` I used `php artisan queue:listen` on the job that runs another job on the different queue.
Looks like `queue:work` only runs that job on the queue and doesn't affect another queue but when I used `queue:listen` it works fine.

A note: This is helped in the windows machine while on linux server it works normally with `php artisan queue:work`